# Java Buffere Reader split add string

Tags: java

I am reading a CSV file of 4GB in java what I have to do is extract 100000 record from file and make a separate file but problem is when I am reading a line
   `line = br.readLine()` and `String[] record = line.split(cvsSplitBy);` it adds one extra `""` in every string like when I open a record array it look like 
`""abc"",""bcd"",""cef"",""dgh"",""elk""` it should be like `"abc","bcd","cef","dgh","elk"`
Kindly let me know why its adding extra commas against every string

Comment: show us your code please

Comment: Use Apache POI or Jxl API's . These API's are very good to process the Excel's

Comment: With input that you provided I can only guess that your file looks like:
"string", "another string", "and another", ...
if yes then remove '"'. And removing all those chars from String is not effective so you can try something else, StringBuilder maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post your code so we can investigate. In the mean time you can remove those extra `""` or do something like:

```
line.split("\"" + cvsSplitBy + "\"")
```

Post your code and I'll edit this reply.